# Проблема с авторизацией пользователя через VK API с использованием технологии Spring OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, oauth

При попытке авторизации через вк прилетает ошибка error_msg -> User authorization failed: no access_token passed. Кроме вк авторизуюсь через гугл, discord и ещё пару сервисов, и там всё работает.
Вот скриншот настройки приложения в вк:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот конфигурация для vk:

```
# VK Oauth2 configuration
vk.client.clientId=***
vk.client.clientSecret=***
vk.client.accessTokenUri=https://oauth.vk.com/access_token
vk.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://oauth.vk.com/authorize
vk.client.tokenName=code
vk.client.scope=email
vk.client.redirectUri=http://mysite.mysite/login/vk
vk.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
vk.client.authenticationScheme=query
vk.client.authorizationGrantType=authorization_code
vk.resource.userInfoUri=https://api.vk.com/method/users.get
```

Все важные компоненты здесь:
[SecurityConfig](https://pastebin.com/vQUNJJSN),  [AuthProvider](https://pastebin.com/zvgwPWVk), [DiscordHttpRequestFactory](https://pastebin.com/DK0A4baB)

Предполагаю, что неправильно сделан конфиг, но уже несколько суток не могу ничего с этим поделать. Прошу помочь!

Comment: У ВК так себе API сделано. Попробуйте посмотреть исходники тут https://github.com/mohaxspb/dont-play-with-gp-api/blob/master/src/main/resources/application-dev.yml и тут: https://github.com/mohaxspb/dont-play-with-gp-api/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/ru/kuchanov/gp/configuration/SocialAuthConfiguration.kt - Для ВК надо по особенному слать запрос + прокидывать пару парамтров вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена, когда я просто изменил конфиг:

```
# VK Oauth2 configuration
vk.client.clientId=
vk.client.clientSecret=
vk.client.accessTokenUri=https://oauth.vk.com/access_token
vk.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://oauth.vk.com/authorize
vk.client.authenticationScheme=query
vk.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
vk.resource.userInfoUri=https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?v=5.52
```